# Is it a good practice to make a method which modifies data outside the class const?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

I would like to ask a question about methods' const-correctness. Let me illustrate the situation.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    ...
    void DiscussedMethod() { otherClass->NonConstMethod(); }

private:
    OtherClass *otherClass;
};
```

I have a class `MyClass` which keeps a pointer to `OtherClass`. In `DiscussedMethod` it calls `OtherClass::NonConstMethod` which modifies some visible data.

I would like to know, whether it would be a good practice to make the `DiscussedMethod` `const` (since it doesn't modify any member data)? Would it be a bad practice? Or is both fine?

What if the `OtherClass` kept a pointer to the `MyClass` and in `NonConstMethod` modified some of the `MyClass`' data (meaning that the `MyClass` member data would change during the `DiscussedMethod` call). Would it be a bad practice to make the `DiscussedMethod` `const` then?

As far as I've been able to find out, the `const` on a method is mostly a code documenting thing, so I would probably lean toward to not making the `DiscussedMethod` `const`, but I would like to hear your opinions.

**EDIT:** Some replies take the into account whether the object pointed to by `otherClass` is owned by the `MyClass` object. This is not the case in the scenario I'm working with. Lets say that both objects exist independently side by side (with the ability to modify each other). I think this analogy describes my situation quite well.

For example consider something like doubly-linked list, where each element is a class that keeps pointer to its neighbours and member variable `color`. And it has method `MakeNeighboursRed` which changes the `color` of its neighbours but doesn't affect the calling object's state itself. Should I consider making this method `const`?

And what if there was some possibility that `MakeNeighboursRed` would call neighbour's `MakeNeighboursRed`. So in the end the state of the object for which `MakeNeighboursRed` has been called originally would change as well.

And I would like to thank you all for your opinions :-)

Comment: This is just my personal opinion. Sometimes the object pointed to I consider "part of the main object". That means, I probably would have made `OtherClass` a full member, but it needed to be dynamic/polymorphic/etc. In that case, I would not make the function const, even though it could be.

Comment: Regarding your edit: I stick to my answer: If calling a method may alter your object's state than it should not be const. (I.e. you alter the neighbour which in turns perhaps changes this state.) I'd expect a const method to preserve the object's state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `MyClass` owns the `OtherClass` instance i wouldn't make `DiscussedMethod` constant.

The same goes for classes, managing resources. I.e. the standard containers do not return non const references or pointers to the managed memory using const functions, although it would be "possible" (since the actual pointer holding the resource is not modified).

Consider

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    bool a() const { return otherClass->SomeMethod(); }
    void b() const { otherClass->NonConstMethod(); }
private:
    OtherClass *otherClass;
};

void foo (MyClass const &x)
{
    cout << boolalpha << x.a() << endl;
    x.b(); // possible if b is a const function
    cout << boolalpha << x.a() << endl;
}
```

The `foo` could print two different values although an implementor of `foo` would probably expect that two function calls on a const object will have the same behaviour.

For clarification:

The following is invalid according to the standard since the const version of `operator[]` returns `std::vector<T>::const_reference` which is a constant reference to the value type.

```
std::vector<int> const a = { /* ... */ };
a[0] = 23; // impossible, the content is part of the state of a
```

It would be possible if  there was only one signature of this function, namely `referece operator[] (size_t i) const;`, since the operation does not alter the internal pointers of the vector but the memory they point to.

But the memory, managed by the vector is considered to be part of the vectors state and thus modification is impossible through the const vector interface.

If the vector contains pointers, those pointer will still be unmodifiable through the public const vector interface, although the pointers stored in the vector may well be non const and it may well be possible to alter the memory they point to.

```
std::vector<int*> const b = { /* ... */ };
int x(2);
b[0] = &x; // impossible, b is const
*b[0] = x; // possible since value_type is int* not int const *
```

Comment: `"the standard containers do not return non const references or pointers to the managed memory using const functions"` Please elaborate, and consider `const vector<int*> v = {..}; *v[0] = 2;`

Comment: @NeilKirk : In your example `v[0]` returns a constant reference to a non constant pointer to int. `*v[0]=2;` does not alter the pointer but the memory the pointer points to. (`v[0] = &some_int;` would be impossible) Essentially it exhibits the same "problem"/behaviour as the question itself (`T * const` is not the same as `T * const *`.)

Comment: `otherClass->NonConstMethod();` doesn't modify the pointer, but the memory it points to (potentially) and operator[] is const in this case.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah but the pointer owned by `vector<int*>` is not the `int*` but (likely) the `int**` member of the vector. Which is the equivalent to the `OtherClass*` member in the question. And the const version of the member function `operator[]` does not alter the memory pointed to by the member of the vector. Your example has one more level of indirection.

Answer (score 4):

In OOP object should be fully described by its *state*, available through its *interface*. Thus, const methods should not alter object's state, if these changes might be observed through the interface.

A good example is a `mutable` mutex inside your class to guard some shared resources. It might be modified from `const` method, since it does not introduce any changes observable via class interface.

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb is, that if you can make a member function const, you probably should. The reason for that is that it allows you to catch unintended behaviour and bug easier.

Another argument in favor would be that if you have this function as const you are allowed to call it on const object, so it isn't really a documentation thing.

Answer (score 2):

Overall it depends what the other class is. It's not black and white...

If `otherClass` is a log object (for example) and you want to log the operation of the current object then it's perfectly fine calling it from a const function.

If the `otherClass` is a container that for design (or implementation) purposes is implemented as a separate object than effectively a const function **modifies the object** making this a very bad idea.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's totaly incorrect to make `DiscussedMethod` `const` as it changes it's `*this` state.  The only loophole to this is making *non-logically*-part-of-object's-state member data `mutable` so they can be changed in `const` functions.  This would be things like a member that hold a count for "number of times function `x()` has been called".  Any thing else is part of the object's *state*, and if a function changes it (at *any* level), that function isn't `const`.

Comment: What do you mean by totally incorrect? It compiles, so it must be a little bit correct*. It does not technically modify `*this` as far as the compiler is concerned. (* joke)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know, whether it would be a good practice to make the DiscussedMethod const (since it doesn't modify any member data)?

`otherClass` **is** member data, and it (or rather, the object it points to) gets modified.

Consider the semantics should the pointer to `otherClass` be refactored to a fully-owned object... whether something is held as a pointer, reference, or object doesn't change the semantical ownership, IMO.

Comment: We don't have enough context to know whether `otherClass` has the semantics of a fully-owned object. Consider `const vector<int*> v = {..}; *v[0] = 2;`