# Should I declare a method const, when underlying OpenGL state is modified

Tags: c++, opengl, methods, constants

The following class encapsulates the OpenGL name of a buffer and provides a few methods for changing the state of the buffer:

```
class BufferObject {
    public:
        explicit BufferObject( GLenum type );
        virtual ~BufferObject();

        // some methods omitted

        void    dataStore( GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid* data, int usage );
        void*   mapBufferRange( GLintptr offset, GLsizeiptr length, int accessFlag );
        void    unmapBuffer() const;
    private:
        GLuint object_;
};
```

None of these methods change the state of the `BufferObject` object, so they could all be declared with `const`. However, `dataStore` and `mapBufferRange` both call OpenGL methods which change the state of the object on the GPU (`glBufferData` and  `glMapBufferRange`, respectively). I would like to declare them without `const` to indicate that they are modifying the state on the GPU.

What is the best practise to follow in this situation?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25972249/183120) has a decent explanation on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that since they don't modify the actual state of the object itself, you can choose.

While there is no hard-and-fast rule, "use `const` wherever possible" is definitely not the universal way to go. Refer to functions like `std::vector::operator[]`—that doesn't change the members of the `vector` object, but stills provide a non-`const` version (and a different `const` version).

One good way of looking at this is: assume you have a `BufferObject`, and you pass it to a function which takes a `const BufferObject&`. Will it mess up your expectations (invariants you expect to hold) if that function calls `dataStore()`? If so, do not mark `dataStore()` as `const`.

To address your particular case, I think you're correct and should leave these functions non-`const`. While they don't modify the physical contents of the C++ object, they *do* modify the logical state of the entity represented by that C++ object.

Comment: deleted my answer since yours says the same thing in much better words